# Spring Boot 1.5.8.Release - Spring Data Mongo PropertyReferenceException

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

After Upgrading form Spring Boot 1.5.7.Release to Spring Boot 1.5.8.Release I get the following Exception:
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property searchByMongoQuery found for type Auto!
The same classes worked like a charm in 1.5.7. Has anyone got a clue what has changed from 1.5.7 to 1.5.8?

Here are my classes:

```
public interface AutoRepositoryCustom {
    Page<Auto> searchByMongoQuery(String value, Pageable pageable);
}

public class AutoRepositoryImpl implements AutoRepositoryCustom {

    private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public AutoRepositoryImpl (MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        Assert.notNull(mongoTemplate, "MongoTemplate must not be null!");
        this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
    }
    @Override
    public Page<Auto> searchByMongoQuery(String rawMongoQuery, Pageable pageable) {......}
}


@RepositoryRestResource()
public interface AutoRepository
        extends MongoRepository<Auto, String>, AutoRepositoryCustom {
}
```

Has anyone got a clue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to resolve the issue by moving the AutoRepositoryImpl to a subpackage of where the AutoRepository class was placed.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11005#issuecomment-343893741) comment on **Github**:

> **the implementation (Impl) class has to be in the same package as the Repository interface.**